# Laravel hasMany relation returns ' Not unique table/alias' error

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm, many-to-many, lumen

**Context**

In Laravel/Lumen 5.5 I have a many-to-many relation defined in my model class `SchemaTypes`, using a pivot tabel `schema_parent_type`:

```php
public function parents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('SchemaParentType', 'schema_parent_type', 'type_id', 'parent_id' );

}
```

I can attach a new parent without problems using this code:

```php
$type = SchemaTypes::where('name', $parentName)->first();
if ( $type)
{
      $type->parents()->attach($parent->id);
}
```

When I check the table `schema_parent_type` after attaching a new 'parent' it looks perfect.

**Problem**

The problem arises when I want to query for all parents given a specific object. When I use this code:

```php
$type = SchemaTypes::where('name', $parentName)->first();
$parents = $type->parents()->get();
```

this results in the following error:

```php
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1066 Not unique table/alias: 'schema_parent_type' 
(SQL: select `schema_parent_type`.*, `schema_parent_type`.`type_id` as `pivot_type_id`, `schema_parent_type`.`parent_id` as `pivot_parent_id` from `schema_parent_type` inner join `schema_parent_type` on `schema_parent_type`.`id` = `schema_parent_type`.`parent_id` where `schema_parent_type`.`type_id` = 110 and `schema_parent_type`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

**Question**

What is the reason that calling `$type->parents()->get()` produces this error? How can I solve this?

Any comments or answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the first argument to another model:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('SchemaTyp‌​es', 'schema_parent_type', 'type_id', 'parent_id' );
```

More information can be found here: [SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias on relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059595/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1066-not-unique-table-alias-o). Look at David Lartey his note.