# Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000) SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, mysql-error-1064

trying to execute the following query on the FriendController

```
$friends = Auth::User()->friends;
```

and that is the friends function on the User model

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Friend', 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}
```

but on hitting the route i get the following error

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'friends' (SQL: select `friends`.*, `friends`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `friends`.`friend_id` as `pivot_friend_id` from `friends` inner join `friends` on `friends`.`id` = `friends`.`friend_id` where `friends`.`user_id` = 2)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059595/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1066-not-unique-table-alias-o

Comment: Check your models `User.php` and `Friends.php` to see if they are not both pointing to the same table in the `protected $table` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[42000\]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias on relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059595/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1066-not-unique-table-alias-o)

Comment: @AnwarNairi i didn't add such attribute.

Comment: @Devon i understanded the concept but i don't know how to do that in the eloqunt ?

Comment: Have you created a pivot table?  You need to specify the pivot table to use.

Comment: Yes, friends is the pivot table, it has 2 ids for friends users.

Comment: @IslamMansour, ok I understand now.  User is the entity, friends in the pivot table.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot tables should almost never have a model.  If you're trying to use `friends` as a pivot table for two users, then the relationship should be referencing `App\User`, not `App\Friend` (or static which represents the current class).

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(static::class, 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}
```

You'd want to return a collection of users, not "friends" since friend isn't an entity, it's a relationship.

Comment: What returns null?

Comment: i tried both solutions and pass it to the view then print it in json format, then it only gets null

Comment: belongsToMany should never return null, only an empty collection,so you must be doing something else wrong

Comment: yes, i did something wrong, but now it worked, Thank you very much.